# List shows null value in another class using java server faces

Tags: java, list, jsf-2

I have an object List<...> and I have using it in my xyz java class its stored some data in its memory successfully and I can use it within xyz class but i have one another class as abc and I want to use this List<...> in it , but when I create an object of my xyz class in abc class and set the getter of my List<...> it shows me null. 
I am using Java Server Faces.

```
public class xyz{

 private List<Car> trackReportData;

public void getTrackData(){

try {
                totalFuelConsumedForAllTrip = 0;
                totalRefueling = 0;
                totalDuration = "";

                int minutes, hours;
                minutes = hours = 0;

                for (RefuelEventBean reb : refuelDataLog) {
                    totalRefueling += reb.getRefuelLiters();

                }

                int totalTheftLiters = 0;
                for (RefuelEventBean reb : theftDataLog) {
                    totalTheftLiters += reb.getRefuelLiters();
                    System.out.println("theftDataLog recrods =" + reb.getRefuelLiters());
                }

                int firstVal = tripDataLog.get(0).getFuelLiter1();
                int lstVal = tripDataLog.get(a).getFuelLiter2();
                totalFuelConsumedForAllTrip = firstVal + totalRefueling - lstVal - totalTheftLiters;
                totalFuelConsumedForAllTrip = totalFuelConsumedForAllTrip < 0 ? totalFuelConsumedForAllTrip * (-1) : totalFuelConsumedForAllTrip;

                for (TripEventBean teb : tripDataLog) {
                    teb.setSerialNo(counterTripDue++);
                    tDuration += teb.getDuration();
//                    totalConsumedLtr += teb.getTotalFuelLiter() < 0 ? 0 : teb.getTotalFuelLiter();
//                    ttlRefuel += teb.getRefueling();

                }

                if (tDuration > 0) {

                    minutes = (int) (((tDuration / 1000) / 60) % 60);
                    hours = (int) ((tDuration / 1000) / 3600);
                }
                String min = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : "" + minutes;
                String hour = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : "" + hours;

                totalDuration = "" + hour + ":" + min;

                //Start to End time 
                //start time:     
                Calendar strTime = tripDataLog.get(0).getParam1().getDateTime();
                //end time
                Calendar endTime = tripDataLog.get(a).getParam2().getDateTime();

                //System.out.println("totalDuration" + totalDuration);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setTotalConsumedLtr(totalFuelConsumedForAllTrip);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setTotalTheftFuel(totalTheftLiters);

                dailyTrakingReportBean.setTotalTrips(numberOfTrips);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setTotalDuration(totalDuration);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setTotalKmRun(totalDistance);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setStartTime(strTime);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setEndTime(endTime);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setMaxTemp(maxTemp);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setMinTemp(minTemp);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setTotalCommercialPowerOff(cpOffCounter);
                dailyTrakingReportBean.setTotalRefueling(totalRefueling);

                c = new Car(id, customer, vehicle, unit, dailyTrakingReportBean, param);

                totalConsumedLtr = 0;
                trackReportData.add(c);                
                dailyTrakingReportBean = new DailyTrakingReportBean();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error in duration");
            }


      }

 public List<Car> getTrackReportData() {

        return this.trackReportData;
    }

    public void setTrackReportData(List<Car> trackReportData) {
        this.trackReportData = trackReportData;
    }


}

//another class where i am using my List:

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class abc{

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{xyz}")

    xyz dtb;

   // private List<Car> fleetReportData;

    //Kilometer Driven
    private BarChartModel animatedModel1;


    public abc() {

//      fleetReportData = new ArrayList<>();
        dtb = new DailyTrackingBean();
        List<Car> fleetReportData = dtb.getTrackReportData(); //null

    }
```

Comment: The `trackReportData` variable was never initialized for the `DailyTrackingBean` instance that you've created in the `abc` constructor, you need to get a reference to the `DailyTrackingBean` instance that has the `trackReportData` variable initialized or call `getTrackData()` before `getTrackReportData()` on this new instance.

Comment: sorry it is initialized in its constructor I forgot to share constructor.

Comment: DailyTrackingBean is nothing it just my xyz class

Answer (score 0):

If trackReportData is initialized in the constructor with a new as per the comment (Not sure because you have not given the full code), Since you call
dailyTrakingReportBean = new DailyTrakingReportBean(); after the end of your method, it will be reinitialized to empty. 
Since you are saying that you are getting null not empty there is something else happening.
Can you post the full code of a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example to figure out the problem.